karateclub MUSAE embedding produces strange number of columns
I'm experimenting with attributed node embeddings and the structural embeddings, but the karateclub implementations give back matrices with strange numbers of columns.
MUSAE gives 128 'features' instead of the requested 32.  GLEE gives 33 when I requested 32.  Am I missing something?
import random
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

from karateclub.node_embedding.attributed import MUSAE
from karateclub.node_embedding.neighbourhood import GLEE

g = nx.newman_watts_strogatz_graph(50, 10, 0.2)

X = {i: random.sample(range(150),50) for i in range(50)}

row = np.array([k for k, v in X.items() for val in v])
col = np.array([val for k, v in X.items() for val in v])
data = np.ones(50*50)
shape = (50, 150)

X = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=shape)

model = MUSAE(dimensions=32)
model.fit(g, X)
emb = model.get_embedding()
print(emb.shape)

model = GLEE(dimensions=32)
model.fit(g)
emb = model.get_embedding()
print(emb.shape)

Output:
(50, 128)
(50, 33)


For MUSAE, if you read the paper, you'll see that they derive the concept directly from Doc2Vec, which is a skipgram based embedding method widely used in NLP. The window_size which is a parameter in the function MUSAE, is the reason you see the behavior in question. The dimension of the embeddings returned is d*(t+1), where d is the dimension you specify and t is the window_size.
By default, the value is 3, and hence the resulting dimension is 128 (32*4). In theory, window_size corresponds to context size, which means how far you travel from a root node to create the vocabulary. So if you want 32 dimensional embeddings, you would want to pass 8 instead of 32 as the parameter.
Note that changing the window_size parameter value also changes the number of dimensions, but in this case it would be impossible to get 32 dimensional embeddings while d is passed as 32, since you would have to pass 0 as the window_size and that is not allowed. Additionally, sometimes it will not allow you to decrease the window_size below a certain value, since you need some context to build vocabulary and capture the structure.
I am not sure what happens in case of GLEE, but it seems like it is generating embeddings that are 1 plus the specified dimension. Here you would have to pass 31 to get 32 dimensional embeddings. I do not know the inner workings of this algorithm.
